# Switched to JakartaMail org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender InputStreamResource from byte array

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I'm moving from mailx to Jakarta.

https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/migrate/jakarta/javaxmailtojakartamail

or with IntelliJ

[image]

```java
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator;
...snip


        try {
           MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = mimeMessage -> {
                MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage,true);
                messageHelper.setFrom("4flutteratk@gmail.com");
                messageHelper.setTo(InternetAddress.parse("4flutteratk@gmail.com"));
                messageHelper.setSubject("error log");
                messageHelper.setText(" Please find attachment:");

                //attachment
                byte[] data;
                if (emailDTO.getIsForCheckIn()) {
                    data = pdfService.generatePDFForCheckIn(emailDTO);
                } else if (emailDTO.getIsForPaymentRefund()) {
                    data = pdfService.generatePDFForRefund(emailDTO);
                } else {
                    data = pdfService.generatePDFForOnlineBooking(emailDTO);
                }

                String fileName = String.format("Booking-%s.pdf",emailDTO.getOnlineRentSell().get_id()).replace(":","");
                ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                messageHelper.addAttachment(fileName, new InputStreamResource(byteArrayInputStream) );
            };

            // Sending the mail
            javaMailSender.send(messagePreparator);
        }

        // Catch block to handle MessagingException
        catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex);
        }
```

This results in an error:

> Passed-in Resource contains an open stream: invalid argument. JavaMail
> requires an InputStreamSource that creates a fresh stream for every
> call.

It works with a local file

```java
FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource("/Users/work2/Documents/GitHub/srr-all6/srr-online-shop-backend/src/main/resources/error.jpeg");
messageHelper.addAttachment(file.getFilename(), file);
```

But not from byte

```
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
// ByteArrayResource byteArrayResource = new ByteArrayResource(data);
String fileName = String.format("Booking-%s.pdf",emailDTO.getOnlineRentSell().get_id()).replace(":","");
// ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
messageHelper.addAttachment(fileName, new InputStreamResource(byteArrayInputStream) );
```

Working but bad TMP file:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile(prefix, ".pdf", null);
tmpFilename.set(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
fos.write(byteArray);

FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(tmpFilename.get());

messageHelper.addAttachment(fileName, file);
```

Could someone please point me to a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [`ByteArrayResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ByteArrayResource.html) instead of wrapping a byte array in a `ByteArrayInputStream` and wrapping that in an `InputStreamResource`.

The documentation of `ByteArrayResource` even helpfully states (emphasis mine):

> Useful for loading content from any given byte array, without having
> to resort to a single-use InputStreamResource. **Particularly useful
> for creating mail attachments from local content, where JavaMail needs
> to be able to read the stream multiple times**.

(JavaMail is the old name for JakartaMail.)

Comment: thx :)
ByteArrayResource byteArrayResource = new ByteArrayResource(data); messageHelper.addAttachment(fileName, byteArrayResource);